How to stop image overlapping text with relative position
I have placed an image towards the top of the page and to the right of some text, but when I resize the browser the image (composting-machine) overlaps the H1 text, even though it doesn't overlap the other text.
How do I fix this and make sure the title text wraps around the image when resizing the browser while keeping the image in the same position?
Here is my code:


body {
    margin: 2.5em;
    margin-left: 5em;
    margin-right: 5em;
    margin-bottom: 0em;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 3.5em;
    margin-top: 0.2em;
    margin-bottom: 0em;
    width: 70%;
}

#composting-machine {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25em;
    float: right;
    position: relative; top: -12em;
}
<div class="overview-container"><header>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="Manatzura Logo" id="logo">
        <h1>LIDA - COMPOSTING MADE EASY</h1>
    </header></div>
    <section class="page1">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="Composting Machine" id="composting-machine">
        <ul>
            <li>ODOUR FREE</li>
            <li>AUTOMATED</li>
            <li>FAST PROCESSING</li>
        </ul>
        <p>Designed for the kitchen, the in-vessel composting system, LIDA reduces kitchen food waste through an automated process. By providing optimal conditions for the microorganisms, LIDA improves the composting process drastically, cutting processing time to roughly a week and curing  time to a month. The result is high quality fertiliser that is nutritious for the soil.</p>
    </section>




The image is floated right within the section element, but the header is outside that section - and then you move the image up by 12em. If you want everything to be to the left or wrapped round that image then put it all in the same element.

I tried that but still had the same problem

Do you want the title to be above everything else or to the left of the image?

For the desired outcome, first wrap the whole text in one div. Now, your code should look something like this looks like this:
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="Composting Machine" id="composting-machine">
<div>
   <h1>Your Heading</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>ODOUR FREE</li>
        <li>AUTOMATED</li>
        <li>FAST PROCESSING</li>
    </ul>
    <p>Designed for the kitchen, the in-vessel composting system, LIDA reduces kitchen food waste through an automated process. By providing optimal conditions for the microorganisms, LIDA improves the composting process drastically, cutting processing time to roughly a week and curing time to a month. The result is high quality fertiliser that is nutritious for the soil.</p>
 </div>
 

Now remove position:relative from css
    #composting-machine {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 25em;
      float: right;
  }   



#composting-machine {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25em;
  float: right;
}
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="Composting Machine" id="composting-machine">
<div>
  <h1>Your Heading</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>ODOUR FREE</li>
    <li>AUTOMATED</li>
    <li>FAST PROCESSING</li>
  </ul>
  <p>Designed for the kitchen, the in-vessel composting system, LIDA reduces kitchen food waste through an automated process. By providing optimal conditions for the microorganisms, LIDA improves the composting process drastically, cutting processing time
    to roughly a week and curing time to a month. The result is high quality fertiliser that is nutritious for the soil.</p>
</div>




This can't work because the img is outside the elements that are required to float around it.

I have corrected the issue the issue was not because of outside elements but it was because of img was under them. I have added a snippet
